# C2143 in nested template class

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T>
class Edge;

template <class T>
class Vertex;

template <class T>
class Vertex
{
    T key;
    char color;
    std::vector<Edge> adjVertices;
};

template <class T>
class Edge
{
    Vertex* source;
    Vertex* target;
};
```

Gives me error in line: `std::vector< Edge > adjVertices;`
`error: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'`
see reference to class template instantiation `'ds::Vertex<T>'` being compiled.

What should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your must

```
#include <vector>
```

and change

```
std::vector<Edge> adjVertices;
```

to

```
std::vector<Edge<T>> adjVertices;
```

The same applies to:

```
Vertex<T>* source;
Vertex<T>* target;
```

Next you'll face the problem that `Vertex` is defined before `Edge`. You should reverse the order.

Comment: +1 Also, in case of C++03 there should be a space between >>: `std::vector<Edge<T> > adjVertices;`

Comment: @dark_charlie: unless your C++03 compiler supports it as an extension. MSVS >= 2005 (OP's compiler) does.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Why not just add the space to make it valid C++ and not depend on a specific toolchain for compilation?

Comment: @Tomalak: for ideological reasons. It had to be valid in C++98, but some vendors decided they cannot afford it.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I don't follow.

Comment: After the classes have been forward declared, does it matter which is defined before/after? ........ once I have delcared template <class T>
class Edge;
....
template <class T>
class Vertex;
..... does the definition order matters?

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Edge;

template <class T>
class Vertex;

template <class T>
class Vertex
{
    T key;
    char color;
    std::vector<Edge <T> > adjVertices;
};

template <class T>
class Edge
{
    Vertex <int> * source;
    Vertex <int> * target;
};
```